# PayPal ExpressCheckout Limit ship to country

Tags: paypal

I'm adding PayPal ExpressCheckout to a website and I want to limit the country that we ship to. It's clearly marked on our site we only ship to the UK but still some people go through our current checkout and try to enter Non-UK addresses, I want to avoid this with PayPal.

Is there a way to restrict the "ship to" country during the SetExpressCheckout?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run GetExpressCheckoutDetails when the customer returns from PayPal.  If the shipping address does not meet your criteria, display an error and a link to go back to the PayPal checkout and resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that is an option I had been considering, but I was looking for a better solution. Sending customers back to PayPal will probably increase cart abandonments. Whereas if there was a way to limit addresses, as we can with other payment providers, it would cut down on user frustration.

Comment: By the way, did you originally start your answer with "Perhaps using the CALLBACK API, but that may be overengineering things"? I have that in my inbox, but the message links back to your answer, and I was worried that perhaps my inbox was broken!